# oracle - sqlcl.exe login error: Could not initialize class sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlcl

Using oracle's sqlcl, I was able to use SPOOL to create data dump files on my dev computer. However, when I tried to run sqlcl on a windows server, with java installed, it gave this error:

> C:\path>sql.exe username/password@connection_string
>
> SQLcl: Release 20.3 Production on Fri Jan 08 13:41:39 2021
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> USER          = username
>
> URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@connection_string
>
> Error Message = Could not initialize class sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper

It doesn't seem to be rejected by remote database server because I could use SQL developer to access the database. Doesn't seem to be login credential or connection string error either, because I tested the same command on my dev computer and it works.

Searched around and haven't seen a related topic.

SQLcl version: Release 20.3 Production

Java version: "1.8.0_271"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)

############ Edit:

As for the environment variable, it is :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
> Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap;C:\Java\jre1.8.0_271;C:\Java\jre1.8.0_271\bin;C:\Java;C:\oracle\instantclient;C:\oracle

Comment: best guess is there's something off with that Java Home (missing, corrupted JAR)

Comment: The comment by @thatjeffsmith really is the *best* guess; can you open a command prompt on the Windows server and invoke a `set` command to see what environment variables are set for variables starting with JAVA and with ORACLE, and [edit] your question to include those results.